# Block the creation of AMIs of an instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, obfuscation, amazon-ami

I am trying to make a deployment of a python based tool on a client AWS account, where they have full control over permissions and roles. We will deploy some VMs and we were thinking of storing their .pem file in order for us to connect to them in case of any failure in the tool to debug the code.

The problem that we have is that we don't want to obfuscate the code even that we also don't want that the client have access to the source code because it will be easier for us to debug any failure. As we will have the .pem file we were comfortable with the idea that they won't have access to the VMs.

But recently I tried to make an AMI from a VM and share it with another account and I saw that you can create a new VM in that other AWS account with the exact same content of the original one and also with a new .pem file, so if the client makes an AMI of our VMs, they will see the code even that they won't have the .pem file.

Is there any solution that we can develop in order to meet that requirements?

Thank you!

We were thinking of obfuscating and deobfuscate the code when we need to debug, but it does not seem practical for us.

Comment: Sounds like a requirement your legal department can and should solve

Comment: "where they have full control" ... "don't want that the client have access", these two statements contradict each other.  There are numerous ways a determined actor could access data on their own AWS account.